What is the correct format to add a custom XYZ tiles {zoom}/{x}/{y}.png) layer in QGIS 3?
I have tiles loaded for a Leaflet map that work fine in Leaflet but I am having difficulty using these tiles with QGIS.  They are loaded onto AWS. The psudo url is: https://mytiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2019_1025/{z}/{x}/{y}.png  Using QGIS Data Source Manager and selecting XYZ from the Menu, I have added the url but nothing shows up.  There are no errors displayed.  Just nothing happens. Can anyone see what is wrong or let me know how to troubleshoot this?  If I enter the url for a single ZYX tile into a browser, I get the tile.

Edit When I check the debugging panel (Menu => View => Panels => Debugging\Development) I get the following for the request:
"ID": "src\\providers\\wms\\qgswmsprovider.cpp:4669 (QgsWmsTiledImageDownloadHandler::QgsWmsTiledImageDownloadHandler)",
"Initiator": "QgsWmsTiledImageDownloadHandler",
"Operation": "GET",
"Replies": 1,
"Reply": {
  "Cache (result)": "Read from network",
  "Error": "Operation canceled",
  "Error Code": "5",
  "Headers": {},
  "Status": null
},
"Thread": "0x0000019168065410",
"Total time (ms)": 60026,
"URL": "https://mytiles.s3.dualstack.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2020_0102/11/35879/48503.png"

}
Edit 2 When I paste the url from QGIS into a browser I get the following:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>MYTiles/2020_0102/15/8803/10027.png</Key>
<RequestId>VAS3AMYMV7F56NRN</RequestId>
<HostId>W6yGX4zHgcZHDJWeRDj32a/5JbvVpj9fYbfGpsywFRT7XBrgKewAvBWVqfE=</HostId>
</Error>

It looks like I can set-up an AWS user permission.  I'm not sure what I'll need here.

Solution I had to invert the {y} to {-y} to get the correct request.
Working with  https://mytiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2019_1025/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png

are you sure it's z,x,y and not some other order

Yes.  It works fine as ZXY in Leaflet and looking at the directory structure it is ZXY for sure.

look at the debugging panel, to see what requests are generated and sent, check any errors reported there

I posted the error in the main question. "Error Code" 5

Does the URL that QGIS generates work from a browser?

I get the error "The specified key does not exist" It looks like I need to set up this data provider with Keys or something...

It does seem that the {y} value is far off.   The request at zoom 18 is {70556/97014.png} when I look at the leaflet tile for that same area the {x}, {y} is {70556/165126}.  Is there a CRS issue( I tried 900913 and 3857)?

Inverting the y was the Solution.  From the Layers >Properties >Layer Source> URL . https://mytiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2019_1025/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png

For a live Amazon S3 xyz tile server I tested..
http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/{Z}-r{Y}-c{X}.jpg

Which works in QGIS 3.36 without issue.


Thanks @Mapperz.   That worked for sure.  I must have an authentication issue.

when I saw your link I looked up the {-y} inversion and things started working.

@CaryH please post your own answer as an answer - glad you found your solution.

For TMS tiles the Y value in the URL should be inverted {-y}.
In QGIS I right clicked the Layer and selected Properties from the menu.  Then  Source from the left Menu.  I changed the {y} to {-y} in the url in Layer Source.

